# AuthorizeAttribute in Asp .net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application using MVC 5.0. I am converting it into Asp .net core.

In my MVC application, I have created custom attribute that is derived from class "AuthorizeAttribute". I am using two main functions here "AuthorizeCore" and "HandleUnauthorizedRequest".

Can someone help me to implement it using Asp .net core.

```
    public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    private AuthorizationManager Authorize;
    public AuthorizeRolesAttribute()
    {
        Authorize = new AuthorizationManager();
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        //Allow user not login than dont apply permission

        var ControllerName = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();
        var ActionName = httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().ToLower();
        return Authorize.IsControllerAllowed(ControllerName, ActionName);
    }


    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error/UnAuthorizedAccess");
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you include the code you have and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808258) and the [Policy Based Authorization Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies). In .NET Core 2.0, it is no longer necessary to subclass `AuthorizeAttribute` to add custom functionality.